# Saving set-cookie value to browser cookies in React

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios

I get this cookie value from the server and I want to save this to my browser.

```
Set-Cookie: succeeedd=noooo!; Path=/
```

I've tried with

```
   const res = yield axios.post(`${config.authURL}/login`, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Cookie: 'cookie1=value',
      },
    });
```

and

```
const res = yield axios.post(
  `${config.authURL}/login`,
  data,
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  },
  { withCredentials: true })
```

Both are not saving cookies into the browser cookies. How can I save Set-Cookie value to the browser so I can use them for authentication?

Comment: Check [this](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials). The `{ withCredentials: true }` should be in 3rd argument. Not the 4th one.

Comment: is there any way that I can use it with {headers: {}}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `withCredentials: true` as below

```
const res = yield axios.post(
  `${config.authURL}/login`,
  data,
  {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    withCredentials: true
  }
);
```

For more generic configuration,

```
// You can add it in a separate config file
const request = axios.create({ withCredentials: true });

// While making API call
request.post(`${config.authURL}/login`, data, { headers: {...} });
```

Check [here](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

install `universal-cookie` with `npm`

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

axios.post(URL, data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    { withCredentials: true }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    let name = res.data.blobName;
    let value = res.data.blobValue;
    cookies.set(`${name}`, `${value}`);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: But then, how can I get the value from the server and use that to save as a cookie?